# How would you classify a set of DiGraphs in different groups or clutsers based on some particularities ? I can't seem to find a way to do it

Tags: python, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx

I have some DiGraphs and I would like to regroup them based on particularities or similarities that they share but I don't know how to do it. Here are some example of graphs :  [graph1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iuWA.png), [graph2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CybHg.png), [graph3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdF6i.png). (I have like ten thousands of them).

And they are DiGraphs that I made using networkx like that:

```
z = nx.DiGraph()
z.add_nodes_from([0, 100, 200, 100, 200, 300, 600])
z.add_edges_from([(0,100),(100,200),(200,100),(100,200),(200,300),(300,600)])
```

The represent this DiGraph z.
 [image: graph3]

Any idea how to make clusters of these graphs ?

EDIT: The criteria I was thinking about is the presence of loop between some nodes and maybe classify them on that. Because some graphs have different kind of loops.

Comment: This is not a good question for SO. There is likely to be as many answers as readers, if not more. It is not clear what you want to accomplish. Say, I suggest to group by the node count. Would it suit you?

Comment: Hello, Rodrigue. To make it easier for us to respond, can you add a few more details? What is the end goal of what you are trying to do with these >10K digraphs? Also, what makes a good cluster vs a not-so-good cluster? If you specify a few more parameters, there will be people here who can help. Thanks.

Comment: The criteria I was thinking about is the looping between 2 or more steps. Sorry for not being clear enough. I do not ask questions often here..

Comment: Once you precisely define the classification criterion, the matter of classification most probably becomes trivial.

Comment: I've been looking for a way to do it for a while now but didn't manage to find a good solution. I've tried google pagerank algorithm to make clusters but it doesn't group them like I want